# MySQL Table parameters variance

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
=================================
| month | bread | milk | butter |
=================================
| Jan16 | 2.00  | 1.30 | 1.50   |
| Feb16 | 2.05  | 1.29 | 1.52   |
| March | 2.03  | 1.31 | 1.51   |
=================================
```

I want to know how is the variance of prices comparing to the first month.
I want to get something like:

```
=================================
| month | bread | milk | butter |
=================================
| Jan16 | 1.00  | 1.00 | 1.0000 |
| Feb16 | 1.025 | 0.99 | 1.0133 |
| March | 1.015 | 1.01 | 1.0067 |
=================================
```

How do I query something like:

```
SELECT bread[i]/bread[0] AS vBread, milk[i]/bread[0] as vMilk, butter[i]/butter[0] as vButter FROM table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join on January:

```
select a.month, a.bread/b.bread vBread, a.milk/b.milk vMilk, a.butter/b.butter vButter
from mytable a
join mytable b on b.month = 'Jan16';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps. First read the values from the first month into variables and the second query generates the output.

```
SELECT 
  bread,milk,butter 
  INTO @bread,@milk,@butter
FROM mytable
ORDER BY MONTH ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT 
  bread/@bread AS vBread,
  milk/@milk AS vMilk,
  butter/@butter AS vButter
FROM mytable;
```

or put this into one:

```
SELECT 
  bread/@bread AS vBread,
  milk/@milk AS vMilk,
  butter/@butter AS vButter
FROM mytable,(
  SELECT 
  bread,milk,butter 
  INTO @bread,@milk,@butter
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY MONTH ASC
  LIMIT 1 ) AS tmp;
```